# Want to edit page layout in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, border

I need to make my website layout like they have in the link below 
the white frame around images and the label below images on the white part. I am not sure how to do it. And I am familiar with **CSS** and **HTML**.

Any help, please.

https://www.saatchiart.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code as it is pure **`CSS`**
assuming u need the same design as the link have

```
.maindiv \\ ur main div{width:100%; background:#fff;padding:1%;}


.maindiv img \\ ur img inside the div{width:100%;  \\ just in case}

.maindiv p,maindiv a \\ ur label and link {width:100%;text-align:left;}

.maindiv p:first-child{font-weight:bold;font-family: ur choice;} \\ it will change all the occurence of the first label in ur div
.maindiv p:last-child{padding-top:1%;}

\\ to change the last link label
```

Comment: sry i was using mobile to type this code so it is not properly formatted 